# What do I replace PointerEvent in OpenLayers 5 with in OL 6?

Tags: openlayers-5, openlayers-6

Trying to upgrade from OL5.3 to OL6.1 but not sure how to fix this yet.

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#olinteractionmodifyevent-changes

That covers the renaming of MapBrowserPointerEvent

```
import PointerEvent from 'ol/pointer/PointerEvent.js';
import MapBrowserPointerEvent from 'ol/MapBrowserPointerEvent.js';
...

// simulate a click on the map
let event = new PointerEvent('singleclick', {
    clientX: xy[0],
    clientY: xy[1],
    shiftKey: false
});
map.handleMapBrowserEvent(new MapBrowserPointerEvent('singleclick', map, event));
```

but not sure what needs to happen with new PointerEvent() and it does seem to be covered in the changelog.

Thanks,
-Steve

Comment: That change was for v3.17.0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on OL6:

```
import MapBrowserEvent from 'ol/MapBrowserEvent';
let event = {
    coordinate: pnt,
    map: map,
    target: 'map',
    pixel: xy,
    type: 'singleclick'
};
map.dispatchEvent(event);
```